# Validation Summary does not render correctly

Tags: asp.net, validation, web-controls

Has anyone ever seen this and does anyone know how to fix it ...

The validation Summary control seems to be rendering this :

```
error message
<br>
error message
<div style="display: none;" id="summaryID">
</div>
```

Correct me if i'm wrong here but shouldn't my errors be inside that div ... hense the reason you can put a cssclass on the control server side using CssClass="whatever" ?

Or did i miss something?

EDIT :

Just to verify ... this is what i expect it to render :

```
<div style="display: none;" id="summaryID">
error message
<br>
error message
</div>
```

EDIT 2 :

Server side markup that produces this is ...

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ui_ValidationSummary" runat="server" />
```

...
Loads of controls but here's an example (don'twant to over complicate things) :
...

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ui_txtClientDOB" runat="server" />
<asp:RangeValidator ID="ui_RangeValidator_DOB" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ui_txtClientDOB" ErrorMessage="DOB is not valid" MinimumValue="1900/01/01" Type="Date" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RangeValidator>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ui_txtClientDOB" ErrorMessage="DOB is missing" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

If either validator on this textbox has reason to fail the validation the result is as discussed, an empty div tag with an error next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely the div #summaryID is where client side validation errors are show. Use a tool like firebug to see this as you can't do a view source on javascript filled markup. Otherwise, turn off client side validation and do a postback.

Edit

My guess is that you are mixing up the error message that's displayed with the validation control itself instead of inside the validation summary. If you don't supply a text property to the validation controls it will use the error message. Try the following (take away the text property and you'll see what I mean):

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="val" runat="server" CssClass="test" 
    DisplayMode="List" />

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" Text="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" Text="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: I am using firebug ... and thats the resulting rendered code ... my problem is that im trying to style the summary and although its styling the summary's containing div correctly with my chosen css style its not styling the summary messages because they are not being rendered inside that div ... and that happens both client and server side.

Comment: say textbox1 is populated and textbox2 is not ... then the validation summary will render 1 "*" as per your sample ... I am looking to ensure that that * appears inside the div that is supposed to contain the validation summary results. What you have there is similar to what i have on the server accept i have messages in my Text property on each required field validator control. messages that are rendered outside the expected div tag on the client side.

Comment: so your sample would render something like ... 
*
<div style="display: none;" id="val">
</div>

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the validation summary. Put the required field validators somewhere else on a page - in a table, for example, and you'll see that the validators and the summary are quite distinct. The summary just takes the error messages and renders them. The validators have their own renderings.

Comment: i have a table ... with controls and those controls have validators associated with them ... i understand how validation works ... when validation takes place they can produce an error message. My understanding is that the validation summary control rendered the contents of those messages in its own output. as that appears to be what is produced ... the problem is that the output is not in the expected format.